# Finding the correct slope.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

[image]

To determine the slope of the graph of this relation do I take the two points as (4,20), (0,0) and then proceed to take

20-0=20 and 4-0=4,

to divide 20 by 4 to get the slope of 5m?

For the second question I noticed that the slope was negative, and then i ran into confusion.

2. The graph below tracks the descent of a skydiver with an open parachute at 1200 m high. Ken made two attempts to determine the rate of change of the descent of the parachutist because his first attempt did not make sense to him. 
   [image]

I recognize that both of his attempts to find the slope are incorrect, but I am having trouble with finding the real slope. I think the first point is (0,1200) but I don't know how i go about finding the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1), yes, that suffices since every choice gives the same result. This assumes points are (time, distance). But note you have made a slight error in the units, which should be m/sec, not just m.

For (2), the point on the other end of the segment appears to be $(15,0)$, doesn't it? The starting point is $(x_1,y_1) =(0,1200)$ and the ending point is $(x_2,y_2)=(15,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since, the locus of the parachute is linear in nature so its slope is given as that of a straight line passing through $(0, 1200)$ & $(15, 0)$ as follows
$$\text{slope of straight line }=\frac{1200-0}{0-15}=-80\ m/min$$ Negative sign indicates that the parachute is descending.

If the acute angle of linear trajectory of parachute with horizontal is $\theta$ then $$\tan \theta=80$$$$\implies \theta=\tan^{-1}(80)\approx 89.28^\circ$$

Comment: What angle? The only angle this could possibly determine is on a sheet of graph paper with time units drawn to the same scale as distance units. Meh.

Comment: angle of linear trajectory of parachute with the horizontal

Comment: I don't think so. The parachute could be falling perfectly vertically. That doesn't make it fall with infinite velocity, which is what your formula would give.

Comment: As I said, your formula measures the angle *on the graph*, which completely depends on the horizontal and vertical units (time and distance) and has no natural significance.

Comment: Yes, you are right. it doesn't have any importance here

Comment: Except, perhaps, in plotting the graph itself